# What does "occur" means here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I tried to understand this but I couldn't.So please, what does it mean?

> "Shortlisting of names will occur."

I know that "occur" means "happen". But what does it mean (names will happen), though?

Comment: What problem do you face there? What do *you* think 'occur' means?

Comment: No, 'shortlisting of name' will happen!

Comment: I really don't understand what mistake I'm making here. Is it not allowed here to ask about meaning of words? Actually, I find so many questions like mine.If that is the case, I promise not post any more questions. Regards.

Comment: @MohammadM - See our [Details, please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) post on meta for some clearer ideas on how to make questions like this better. In this case, you could (a) add some context (in other words, where did this sentence come from?) and (b) tell us what you found when you looked up _occur_ in the dictionary (in other words, why didn't any of those meanings seem to fit with this sentence?). If you do those two things, you'll see your question get a lot more positive attention. (I started by moving a comment into your question.)

Answer (score 1):

**will occur** means **will happen**

> Shortlisting of names **will occur**
>   Shortlisting of names **will happen**

it is not specified **when** a shorter list of names **will happen**

The breakdown of the sentence is

> [ Shortlisting of names ] [ will occur ]
>   [ gerund + prepositional phrase ][ future verb ]

Comment: Thanks, I've found the meaning (there will be a development of a shortlist of names"

Answer (score 0):

'Be done' is the better word in this context. 'Occur' is used for events which generally happen on their own:

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/occur

> **occur**
>   *verb* (used without object), occurred, occurring.
>   1.
>   to happen; take place; come to pass:
>   *When did the accident occur?*

If not 'done', then we can use happen. 'occur' is generally not used, so it's confusing.